# I need a small parser (jquery) that knows if an input is URL:PORT format

Tags: jquery, parsing, input

You have a user input string from a textbox for example `var strInput = $("#txtBox").val();`

`strInput` has some string now. I need to now if it is of this format: IP:PORT

Basically a user can input something like this: http://192.168.300.22:20000

1) Frist part (protocol): http:// always needs to be replaced by: https://

2) Second part (everything until the ":" sign): 192.168.200.22 (or www.google.com)

3) Third part (port): everyhing after ":"  (example: 9999, 100000)

- I : TAKE THE INPUT

  ```
  var strInput = $("#txtBox").val();
  ```
- II : PARSE THE INPUT
- III : results

  ```
  var strProtocol = "https//";
  var strIP = parsedIP;
  var strPORT = parsedPORT;
  ```

So I need 2 know how to get the values (parsedIP and parsedPORT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this. Pattern:

```
(?<protocol>\w+)://(?<ip>[\d\.]+)(:(?<port>\d+)|)
```